# How to search for an element in an stl list?

Tags: c++, stl

Is there a `find()` function for list as there was in vector?

Is there a way to do that in list?

Comment: `std::vector` has a `find()` method? That's news to me.

Comment: mybad... i meant fint(vectoriterator.begin(),vectoriterator.end(),string)

Comment: You are correct, `std::vector` does not have a `find()` method.

Comment: For large sorted lists, binary_search is more efficient.

Comment: @Marc: lists allow random access already, did I miss something?

Comment: @7vies The binary search is optimal log(n) for sorted data. I'm not sure what point you are making.

Comment: @Marc: binary search requires random access, which lists don't allow (we are talking about STL list here, so it is a linked list not something like ArrayList)

Comment: @7vies Sorry. Right you are -- my mistake. However, it looks like the STL lower_bound algorithm can be used.

Comment: @Marc: yes, but it will still be relatively inefficient. The comparison will only be invoked O(log N) times, but stepping through the iterators will take O(N).

Comment: @Prasanth: if possible, stay away from `std::list` unless your container requirements dictate that you should use it. It's the most space inefficient container available in the STL (for a linear container, that is) and iteration is painfully slow.

Comment: @Matthieu Agreed, but I think still more efficient than plain find(). Though I doubt it is worth while for small amounts of data.

Comment: @Marc: actually it's especially worthwile for complicated `operator<` the cost of a branch pales before the cost of a memory access.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) from `<algorithm>`, which works equally well for `std::list` and `std::vector`. `std::vector` does not have its own search/find function.

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> ilist;
    ilist.push_back(1);
    ilist.push_back(2);
    ilist.push_back(3);

    std::list<int>::iterator findIter = std::find(ilist.begin(), ilist.end(), 1);
}
```

Note that this works for built-in types like `int` as well as standard library types like `std::string` by default because they have `operator==` provided for them. If you are using using `std::find` on a container of a user-defined type, you should overload `operator==` to allow `std::find` to work properly - see [`EqualityComparable` concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/EqualityComparable).

Comment: What's the time complexity of `std::find()` ? Perhaps, O(n) ?

Comment: No binary seach capabilities for a sorted container? Lazy implementation.

Comment: @LDS - `std::binary_search` provides binary searches.

Comment: string has the find series functions.  Not sure other containers do not.

Comment: `std::binary_search` only returns `true` or `false`. I think the OP may be  interested in `LB = std::lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),value)`.
Then `LB` is an iterator to the first element >= `value` we look for. Iff `*LB==value`, then  `LB - v.begin()` is the index of `value`.

Comment: I would like to add that when one use find, the type of the container element and the type of the val to search does not need to match! The only thing is the the operator== of the container elements need to be defined for the type of the val to search. Might be useful sometimes...

Answer (score 25):

No, not directly in the `std::list` template itself. You can however use `std::find` algorithm like that:

```
std::list<int> my_list;
//...
int some_value = 12;
std::list<int>::iterator iter = std::find (my_list.begin(), my_list.end(), some_value);
// now variable iter either represents valid iterator pointing to the found element,
// or it will be equal to my_list.end()
```

Answer (score 22):

Besides using `std::find` (from algorithm), you can also use [`std::find_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) (which is, IMO, better than std::find), or other find algorithm from [this list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/)

---

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> myList{ 5, 19, 34, 3, 33 };
    

    auto it = std::find_if( std::begin( myList ),
                            std::end( myList ),
                            [&]( const int v ){ return 0 == ( v % 17 ); } );
        
    if ( myList.end() == it )
    {
        std::cout << "item not found" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        const int pos = std::distance( myList.begin(), it ) + 1;
        std::cout << "item divisible by 17 found at position " << pos << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is find_if better? If you are searching for an element that matches with equality, are you saying you would not use find and would use find_if instead?

find_if does allow you custom searching, but if you had to fit in some horrible functor to search for equals it would make code look very ugly compared to using find.

Comment: @CashCow It all depends on what type of element is in the vector or list. Sometimes it is not possible to use std::find.

Comment: Yes, sometimes you need find_if which is why it is part of the library but that doesn't make it "better" such that you would use it even when std::find works.

Comment: +1 if you already have an unary predicate, find_if is better.

Comment: Maybe you should add a little example to **show the advantage**?

Comment: @Wolf Thank you. That is what was missing. Added example now

Comment: Ok, that's an advanced example that requires C++11, well?

Comment: @Wolf Yes. c++11 makes that example a bit simpler. But it is not that hard to convert it to a c++03 example

Comment: Yes, but maybe it should mentioned that this is C++11 code. ...and maybe using `==` for implementing predicate isn't such a good reason ;)

Comment: @Wolf The example is very simple to demonstrate the idea. It is possible to implement something quite complex, that is why `find_if` may be better.

Comment: I mean, you demonstrate that `find_if` is better with a use case where `find` already works well. If the predicate was *divisible by 11* instead, the advantage of `find_if` would be obvious.

Answer (score 4):

What you can do and what you should do are different matters.

If the list is very short, or you are only ever going to call find once then use the linear approach above.

However linear-search is one of the biggest evils I find in slow code, and consider using an ordered collection (set or multiset if you allow duplicates). If you need to keep a list for other reasons eg using an LRU technique or you need to maintain the insertion order or some other order, create an index for it. You can actually do that using a std::set of the list iterators (or multiset) although you need to maintain this any time your list is modified.

Answer (score 1):

No, find() method is not a member of `std::list`.
Instead, use `std::find` from `<algorithm>`

```
    std :: list < int > l;
    std :: list < int > :: iterator pos;

    l.push_back(1);
    l.push_back(2);
    l.push_back(3);
    l.push_back(4);
    l.push_back(5);
    l.push_back(6);

    int elem = 3;   
    pos = find(l.begin() , l.end() , elem);
    if(pos != l.end() )
        std :: cout << "Element is present. "<<std :: endl;
    else
        std :: cout << "Element is not present. "<<std :: endl;
```