# using std::find on a container of a user-defined type c++

Tags: c++

Im trying to write a search function to get an element in std::list by suing std:find. But im stuck in the third parameter in the find argorithm, regard to this guy [How to search for an element in an stl list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604136/how-to-search-for-an-element-in-an-stl-list?answertab=active#tab-top) I did overload the operator == pretty much but it seems still not working with the std::find.

This is my code:

```
class Node
{
    string word;
    int count;

    public:
        Node(string _word) :word(_word), count(0) {}
        ~Node() {}

        const string& getWord() const{
            return word;
        }
        bool operator == (const Node& other) const {
            return (this->word.compare(other.word) == 0);
        }
};
const Node &getNode(const list<Node> &nodes, const string &word){
    list<Node>::iterator itr;
    itr = find(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), new Node(word)); <-- no viable overload '='
    return *itr;
}
```

I'm going very crazy with that issue now, please suggest me some hints. Thanks

Comment: You have a list of `Node`s, but you're trying to find a pointer. Erase the `new`.

Comment: What do mean erase the new. If like this 
    Node node(word);
    itr = find(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), node);
It still doesnt work

Comment: @anonymous Please, check this. It works. You can also pass in the `string` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the code working just remove the `new` from the `sort`
call. However, this is not going to make your code any better.

You don't check if the element was actually found and just dereference
the iterator. If the element wasn't found, this is undefined behavior.

Now, how to fix this.

1. Don't provide this function. If the user of `Node` has a list, she should be perfectly capable of calling `std::sort` himself.
2. You don't want to write the boiler-plate of wrapping and you don't need to. Your class is convertible from `std::string` due to the single argument constructor taking a `string` (this should take a string by reference, though). So you can just write `std::find(begin(nodes), end(nodes), "foobar");`.
3. You can also mark the constructor explicit (the converting behavior is not wanted most of the time) and then just add two free `operator==(const Node&, const std::string&)` and `operator==(const std::string&, const Node&)`.

In any case. Remove `using namespace std;` from your headers.

Comment: Still a good idea to make your constructor explicit unless you need otherwise.

Comment: @chris Non-explicit can be helpful at times, but it's really delicate. Beginners should certainly avoid it.

Comment: Indeed, unless you have a good reason not to (like int->BigInt), avoiding it leads to less weird errors.

Comment: Can you tell me the reason why we should remove using namespace std; from header

Comment: @anonymous It imports a lot of names into the current scope and makes for a lot of funny ambiguities should you ever try to call something `count`. Don't do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c

Answer (score 1):

You have two main problems:

- First, your `find` call is looking for a pointer to a `Node`. `new` allocates memory and returns a pointer. What you want is that exact text without `new`.

  ```
  itr = find(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), /*new*/ Node(word));
  ```

  Also note that you can use just `word` instead because you provide a constructor with  one string argument, so it will be implicitly converted. This is usually more bad than good though, and you'd be best to declare your constructor as `explicit`.

  ```
  explicit Node(string _word) :word(_word), count(0) {} //need Node("hi")
  ```

  This will lead to less confusing errors in the future. It's a good idea to stick explicit on by default.

---

- Secondly, your main problem. Your function returns a `const string &`. Your iterator is of type `list<Node>::iterator`. These don't match.

  ```
  return *itr; //not const
  ```

  What you need is this:

  ```
  list<Node>::const_iterator itr; //create a constant iterator instead
  ```

  The rest can stay the same and it should work (or at least it did for me).