# How do i know, if i found the number that i searched in a STL list.

Tags: c++, c++11

```
int main(){
list<int> l1;
list<int> :: iterator l1_iter;
int v1 = 10;
int v2 = 5;
l1.push_back(v1);
l1.push_back(v2);
l1.push_back(50);
l1.push_back(100);
l1_iter = find(l1.begin(), l1.end(), 50);
```

I have written this code, i want to search 50 in my list. 
Is there away to know if i found or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search for an element in an stl list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604136/how-to-search-for-an-element-in-an-stl-list)

Comment: See the other answers in the duplicate above, not only the accepted one, for examples testing existence.

Comment: Consider reading some [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Answer (score 2):

`std::find` will return its second argument (`l1.end()` in this case) if the element is not found.